# Testing strategies for testing a Scheduler

Tags: microprocessor, rtos

We have developed an in-house Scheduler which is based on [Rate-monotonic scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate-monotonic_scheduling).
We have 6 tasks (5 actual tasks and 1 idle task). Our scheduler works on 1msec timer interrupt. Before sending it out in the real world, We want to test it thoroughly.

What are the best and/or commonly used strategies for testing a Scheduler?

One thing we performed was added functions which require very high processing time in each task and checked whether scheduler still switches on the given deadline or not. But I feel this is not enough to gain confidence.

Comment: Am I missing something? This sounds like a "pure software" question, which would probably get a better response over on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: I don't think this question would go well on Stack Overflow, but if you don't have any luck here I believe Programmers.SE might be the best choice. They tend to deal with "general approach" questions a bit more, although double-check the help pages I've never posted there.

Comment: I always get confused about where to post questions related to Embedded Software!

Comment: @PeterJ I got better option: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Migrated to http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/testing-strategies-for-testing-a-scheduler

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was related to SQA and I migrated it to SQA.SE

Comment: I'm sure you can break it by disabling the interrupt or executing something with some sort of exception - maybe a floating point, a divide/0, or perhaps a data access out of bounds, or to an an odd address, or just jumping back to the reset vector. It really depends on your cpu features. Generally these are handled by a multi tier execution privelege system
Do you have that in place ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about software